# htaccess protect all website but some paths

Tags: .htaccess

I need to protect all http://domain.com with AuthType Basic, but leave http://domain.com/foo/bar 
(http://domain.com/foo/bar is a rewrite url, not a folder)

I read about location tag but it not work in htaccess file :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase REQUEST_URI "/foo/bar" ExcludePath

AuthName "SiteName Administration"
AuthUserFile /.htpasswd
AuthType basic
Require valid-user

Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=ExcludePath
Satisfy Any
```

Answer (score 0):

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(foo/bar)
>   -- protect howsoever you want --

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(foo/bar)
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /.htpasswd
AuthName "PSPCF3 Admin"
require user admin
</IfModule>
it always ask for password